# How to remove white space below images?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at the code.
There is white space below div that contains image.
How can I remove it?
If I delete doctype, white space would be removed. But I need doctype.

Edit: Also I want .container to be "inline-block" and changing It to "block" will just replace the space from below div to the lower part of the .container and won't remove it.
Sorry for bad English.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.container img {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://openclipart.org/assets/images/images/openclipart-banner.png" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  123
</div>
```

Comment: In the absence of any explanation, there are some nice ones here: [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image). Personally, I can't bring myself to upvote an answer that says "just do this" without explaining the problem and solution.

Comment: @Adib Remove the container class from your second div and add this style to it: `<div style="width: 100%;background: black; color: white; margin-top: -5px;">
  123
</div>`   here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dm4vtoy1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `block` for `.container`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.container img {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://openclipart.org/assets/images/images/openclipart-banner.png" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  123
</div>
```

Comment: Check the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `vertical-align: top` to `.container` class.

Answer (score 0):

Add block to your container:

```
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Check the edited post.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `display:block;` to the element should solve the issue.

Comment: Check the edited post.